# Spinner.setadapter(adapter) keeps failing

Tags: android

The goal is to getting working in the extended view & not in the onCreate
Im pretty sure the problem starts when I declare:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( context,...);
```

I have tried to use `.createFromResource( this,...)` but that wont even compile.
but the program runs fine until I use the `setadapter` function. I have been struggling hard to make this work outside of the `onCreate`.

```
public class main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(new Piano(this));
    }

    private class Piano extends View {
        //keyboard array
        private ShapeDrawable []  keyboard;
        private int indx=0;
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.dbox);
        SurfaceView sandbx = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.sandbox);



        public Piano(Context context){
            super(context);
            context.getSystemService(DROPBOX_SERVICE);

            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    context, R.array.chord_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Listen()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for Spinner :

```
public class Spinner1 extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.spinner_1);

    Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.colors, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s1.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

}

Instead of extending View you can extend Activity..

Answer (score 0):

try to do this instead

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(context, R.array.chord_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the piano() constructor content into the onCreate method or otherwise call piano View in the onCreate method.

Whenever you initialize the android component you should call inside th activity life cycle methods only.

Whether you have piano view (custom view) or any UI component View you should call it in any one of the activity lifecycle methods. or otherwise you should call it in XML as follows :

```
     <com.packagename.PianoView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     .
     .
      />
```

If you accept this vote up for me